# Understanding YUI module loading and attaching

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am using the latest version of the `Yahoo User Interface`.

I am looking at the `YUI global` object's docs and I have some questions.

I would like to know when is a module loaded and when is it attached to a specific instance?

```
YUI().use('calendar', function (Y) {

     // I assume that when we are here that the calendar module has been loaded?

     // But when is it attached to this instance of YUI?

});
```

How do I create multiple YUI sandboxes if the first instance is declared like this:

```
var Y = YUI();

Y.use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
});
```

Would you still pass Y into both instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the second question first:

The `YUI()` function creates the sandbox.  So

```
var Y1 = YUI();
var Y2 = YUI();
```

would be two separate sandboxes, and `Y1` and `Y2` will know nothing about each other.
However you can do something like this.

```
Y1 = YUI();

Y1.use('calendar', function (Y) {
    Y.myCalendar = new Y.Calendar().render(Y.one('body'));
});

setTimeout( function () {

    Y1.use(function (Y) {
        Y.myCalendar.on('dateClick', function (e) {
            alert('date clicked');
        });
    });

}, 100);
```

The global `Y1` becomes the local `Y` in each of the `use` functions. This also illustrates out an answer to your first question.  The `setTimeout` is used in this example because each `use` function attaches modules and runs its functions asynchronously to one another.  Without the `setTimeout` you will most likely get an error from the second `use` because it will run before `myCalendar` is defined by the first `use`.

Each `use` will perform its own lazy loading of modules.  If the modules are already loaded it only needs to attach them to the YUI instance.  In practice most applications only employ one `use` per sandbox.

Of course there's lots more info and details in the [YUI docs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/#understanding-yuiuse).